# What is the timezone for Google URL Shortener stats date fields?

Tags: google-api, url-shortener, google-url-shortener

Specifically: https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/url
the urlshortener.get returns fields like twoHours, day, week for stats.  When does day get reset or which timezone is it calculated from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe those are are all relative. As in `day` is the 24 hours leading up to the time of the request. I just did a quick test by clicking on a shortened URL at 10:45am and the click showed up immediately on the graphs.

[image]